# Is there a way to set every other line in a java text area to a different color?

Tags: java, colors, textarea, line, background-color

I want to set every other line in a java text area to a second color, is there a way to do this?

example:

```
<red>1</red>    
<blue>2</blue>
<red>3</red>    
<blue>4</blue>
```

the red and blue tags are just for example only.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `java.awt.TextArea` nor `javax.swing.JTextArea` support text (or background) decorations.  It is one font & one style.

As indicated by Chris, a `JTextPane` (or `JEditorPane`) is designed for 'styled text' documents.  JEP for example, will handle RTF & (simple) HTML/CSS formatting.